# Element visible via a checkbox in JSXGraph: altering other parameters?

Tags: checkbox, jsxgraph

Assume you have the following elements added to your JSXGraph `board`:

```
var checkbox1 = board.create('checkbox', [1, 0.5, 'Click me']);
var p = board.create('point', [1, 0], {
        visible: function() {return checkbox1.Value();},
        label:{offset:[15,15]}
});
```

Why is it that the presence of the function inside `visible` alters the values given inside `label`? (By commenting the line `visible...`, you notice a difference.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, indeed using a function as value for the attribute `visible` seems to have an influence on the position of the label. But the problem is even more involved:
The default value of the attribute `anchorY` of the label is `middle`, i.e. with the `offset` attribute set to `[0,0]`, the label is centered vertically beside the point `p`.
However, in order to be able to position a label vertically centered, JSXGraph has to know the size of the label's text box. Unfortunately, if the label is created with `visible:false`, the text size can not be determined (for the moment).

In short, the problem is that the point is created with `visible:false`.
If your code would be

```
var checkbox1 = board.create('checkbox', [1, 0.5, 'Click me']);
var p = board.create('point', [1, 0], {
    visible: function() {return !checkbox1.Value();},
    label:{offset:[15,15]}
});
```

the label position is as expected.
A possible workaround would be to user a different value for `anchorY` like:

```
var checkbox1 = board.create('checkbox', [1, 1.5, 'Click me']);
var p = board.create('point', [1, 0], {
    visible: function() {return checkbox1.Value();},
    label:{offset:[15,0], anchorY: 'bottom'}
});
```

See it live at https://jsfiddle.net/1u7geLar/